# MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream of a json file return zip file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, fileinputstream

in my java web-app I have integrated firebase-admin-sdk. To go to retrieve the json file to pass to GoogleCredentials I use MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream (path), doing the cast as follows:

```
FileInputStream targetStream = (FileInputStream) MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream (credentials);
GoogleCredentials.fromStream (targetStream, transportFactory);
```

My problem is that getResourceAsStream gives me a ZipFileInflaterInputStream type instead of InputStream, as a result I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.zip.ZipFile $ ZipFileInflaterInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.FileInputStream.

Unfortunately I can't use the firebase guidelines to import the file.

Would anyone be able to show me a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just **don't** cast returned stream to `FileInputStream`.

```
InputStream targetStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream (credentials);
GoogleCredentials.fromStream (targetStream, transportFactory);
```